# How to get PDF first page and convert it to JPG

Tags: php, imagemagick

Theres a way, using PHP exec and Image MagicK, to get the first PDF page and convert it to JPG?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imagemagick convert pdf to png](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811640/imagemagick-convert-pdf-to-png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [many search results on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pdf+jpg) already.

You have the choice between two duplicates:

- [ImageMagick/Imagick convert PDF to JPG using native PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588918/imagemagick-imagick-convert-pdf-to-jpg-using-native-php-api) using the PHP IM bindings
- [Imagemagick convert pdf to png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811640/imagemagick-convert-pdf-to-png) using the command line.

Note that for this to work, you need Ghostscript installed along with ImageMagick. (I think this usually is the case.)

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question, you convert just the nth page page as follows:

```
convert file.pdf[n] output_file.jpg
```

Note that this is zero based, so for the first page you would want to use `file.pdf[0]`.

If you wish to convert the entire file, you can do:

```
convert file.pdf output_file.jpg
```

And this will produce a bunch of files in the form of `output_file-0.jpg, output_file-1.jpg, ..., output_file-n.jpg`